# Sum date using strtotime always returns 01/01/1970

Tags: php, strtotime

I am trying to add 1 day to a date using `strtotime` but I can´t get it to work. It always returns 02/01/1970

```
$date = date ("d/m/Y H:i:s", filemtime($directory));
$newdate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
$tomorrow = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($newdate . "+1 days"));
echo $tomorrow; //Always return 02/01/1970
```

Comment: What returns `filemtime($directory)`?

Answer (score 0):

Because `strtotime()` differentiates between USA date format and Sensible date format by looking at the date seperator all you need to do is us the `-` seperator if you want to use the sensible date format, like this, in your intermediate date manipulations

```
$date = date ("d-m-Y H:i:s", filemtime($directory));
$newdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
$tomorrow = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($newdate . "+1 days"));
echo $tomorrow; //Always return 02/01/1970
```

> **FROM the manual**
>
> Note:
>
> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-), the date string is parsed as y-m-d.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Better work with `DateTime()`:

```
$date = new DateTime(strtotime(filemtime($directory)));
echo $newdate = $date->format('d/m/Y');
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $tomorrow = $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Output:

```
20/01/2020
21/01/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `filemtime($directory)` returns a string formatted as your `date()` mask, I mean `d/m/Y H:i:s`, then you can do next steps:

- for example, according to this mask, it looks like:

```
$s = "02/06/2019 22:23:22";
```

- now you can do `strtotime()`

```
$date = date ("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($s));
```

- then transform it to the `DateTime` object

```
$st_date = new DateTime($date);
```

- now you can simply modify it as you want

```
$st_date->modify('+1 days');
```

- to see the result string value use:

```
$tomorrow = $st_date->format('d/m/Y');
echo 'tomorrow -> '.$tomorrow;
```

Output:

```
date->02/06/2019 22:23:22
tomorrow -> 03/06/2019
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/0fSHu)**